# Pandas: read_csv with usecols that may not exist in the csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have several large csv with many columns but they do not all have the same set of columns hence different number of columns in each file. And I only want to read columns that contains a certain string call it "abc-".

I created a list of possible column names that contain the string "abc-" and set the `usecol` equal to this when reading the csv using `pd.read_csv`. It gave me an error.

`ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['abc-150']`

What can I do ?

Comment: Use a callable?

Comment: can you provide an example

Comment: From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv): _If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the column names, returning names where the callable function evaluates to True._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
s = """col1,abc,col3,abcde,fghabc"""
​
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), usecols=lambda x: "abc" in x)
```

​
Output :

```
print(df.columns)

Index(['abc', 'abcde', 'fghabc'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, is to read columns first, filter them, then pass them to `usecols` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data="""
col1, col2, abc-col, abc-col2
val1, val2, val3, val4
val5, val6, val7, val8
"""
columns = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), nrows=1).columns
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), usecols=[col for col in columns if 'abc' in col])
df.head()
```